# How to allow VPN traffic to a Docker Container

Tags: iptables, docker, openvpn

I have the following:

```
                                            Docker Host (public IP 5.6.7.8)
(1) Client (IP 1.2.3.4) <--> (2) OpenVPN in a Container (public IP 5.6.7.8, port 1194)
                             (3) App in a Container (public IP 5.6.7.8, port 1234)
```

So, from my phone, I want to connect to my OpenVPN server as a client and after that, I want to connect to my app (e.g. Nextcloud). Probably this is a firewall issue. I want to block all traffic except the one that is coming from the VPN.
I tried different rules and ways to figure it out what I need to do.
So far, I didn't arrive at a solution.

This will block the traffic to the app:

```bash
-A DOCKER-USER -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DROP
```

This will allow it to work:

```bash
-A DOCKER-USER -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4/32 --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT
```

The rule that works for me is not good because I have to add each client's source IP. As far as I know, all the traffic is routed through the VPN (e.g. the public IP changes after I connect to it).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just allow traffic from the OpenVPN server itself?  Basically you are wanting to set up your VPN server as a middleman.

So instead of,

```bash
-A DOCKER-USER -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4/32 --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT
```

do

```bash
-A DOCKER-USER -p tcp -s [VPN_IPv4_ADDRESS] --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: That doesn't work, unfortunately, I tried. Using TCPDump it seems that the traffic from the client is interpreted by the Docker Host as having the source IP 1.2.3.4 instead of [VPN_IPv4_ADDRESS].

Comment: [VPN_IPv4_ADDRESS] would be the IP address of the machine your VPN is on.

Comment: @Mars you can get the IP address of the VPN host by running `ip addr show` on the VPN host (assuming it's Linux-based).

Comment: I tried with the public IP address of the Docker Host (same public IP also for the VPN server).
It is Linux-based. `ip addr show` will present a lot of interfaces, I will add bellow some of them that might be related:
- eno1, 192.168.0.4/24 -> IP from my router |
- docker0, 172.17.0.1/16 -> Docker interface |
- br-38fd1e596448, 172.26.0.1/16 -> interface for my OpenVPN Container |
With what IP you are suggesting me to try?

Comment: Try the router IP and then try the OpenVPN IP.  If neither work, then I will have to revise my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It seems that it is working with the OpenVPN private IP / 24. I probably have to figure out how to get this IP dynamically.